# Text Generating Functions: Do they exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, generating-functions

This is a little far out question, but just curious: is it even possible to have a non-high-degree-polynomial function (as in polynomial regression function) that could generate a sentence of say, 10 letters long.  What about 100 letters, n letters?

for example: is there a function that can generate the letter codes for "hello world" (space not important).  The sequence would be 7 4 11 11 14 22 14 17 11 3

Then, what about 
"the quick dog jumped over the lazy fox"
19 7 4    16 20 8 2 10    3 14 6    9 20 12 15 4 3    14 21 4 17    19 7 4    11 0 25 24    5 14 23

and eventually longer paragraphs...  Is this just crazy to even ponder?
Keep in mind, I'm not looking for a general functions, but ones that specifically generate a given sequence.

Comment: If you choose $n$ many numbers randomly, then probably you will need a polynomial of degree $n-1$ to fit them exactly.

Comment: By 'generate' do you mean some polynomial $p$ such that $p(0) = 7$, $p(1) = 4$, $p(2) = 11$, etc?

Comment: @TrevorWilson English words and sentences are not completely random, so a generic sentence may not need the maximal degree polynomial.

Comment: @BabyDragon Hence the "probably".  Anyway, although English is quite redundant, I would be **very** surprised if this redundancy could be described in terms of polynomials of low degree.

Comment: If you generate enough random polynomials with integer coefficients, then you will eventually have a polynomial that will generate 'The Hitch Hikers guide to the Galaxy'.

Comment: I think that 42 polynomials should be enough to produce the book;). @TrevorWilson I took you comment to mean that the set sequences of legnth $n$ has some probability space structure and that the probability that the minimal interpolating polynomial of the sequence is of degree $n-1$  1. As for the that a generic English sentence I do not have any intuition for that one way or another. A More precise question would be: What is the probability distribution of the degree of the interpolating polynomials, given that the redundancy is bounded below.

Comment: Interesting insights.  Of course, the non-randomness of language (given Index of Coincidence and other properties) make me think that there could be a way to find a lower degree polynomial, or even a different form.  How would one go about exploring such possiblity?

Comment: In the field of formal languages, there are non-polynomial functions that generate the given 'words' of a 'language'...

Comment: @Newb can you elaborate on that? any examples? thanks.